# Validator.TryValidateObject does not validate attribute

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

Using WebApi v2 I've built something that takes an object as argument. I'm using both IValidateableObject and dataannotations for model validations that I trigger using an WebApi filter.

However, one object contains an array of items that all need to be validated. I've created a custom attribute in order to do this using something like [Asp.net Web Api nested model validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448662/asp-net-web-api-nested-model-validation), but I can't get the validation going. Also - I've use the ValidateAllProperties flag already.

So I built a console app to verify the behavior and the validation doesn't seem to be triggered (or I'm calling the API incorrectly). Here's something that does not work for me:

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var s = new Boundary { LowerDecimal = 1.1m };
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(s, new ValidationContext(s, null, null), new List<ValidationResult>(), true);
        Console.WriteLine("Validation resulted in " + isValid);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Boundary
{
    [Range(0,1)]
    public decimal LowerDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

}

isValid always returns true. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT - Also tried defining MetaData class like here: [Validation does not work when I use Validator.TryValidateObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422031/validation-does-not-work-when-i-use-validator-tryvalidateobject)

Comment: Could you show your custom `ValidationAttribute` code? The above will always return true because the `Validator.TryValidateObject` method will only check for the `RequiredAttribute` on each of the properties of the specified type, it doesn't recognize other validation attributes - that's why you need to use a custom attribute. This is stated in the remarks section of the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That Range attribute is inside the framework, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx, also, I've used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772(v=vs.110).aspx with the boolean at the end, indicating 'validateAllProperties, true to validate all properties; if false, only required attributes are validated'

Comment: the code I was referring to was your custom attribute you mentioned you wrote. The documentation is quite confusing, the remarks section appears to contradict what the `validateAllProperties` says. Regardless, I think you are correct this doesn't appear to be the correct behaviour it should probably be validating the `RangeAttribute` on the property.

Comment: Ah sorry for misunderstanding. In order to eliminate possible errors in my code, I created this setup with only standard stuff and I can't even get that to work.

Comment: From your example, it would appear what the remarks says is the defined behaviour. However, maybe there is a step missing for this to work on the properties - will do a bit of digging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `TryValidateObject` is a red herring, the problem actually lies with the `RangeAttribute`.

The problem is the attribute has 2 overloads (one for `int` and one for `double`), in your attribute definition you have declared `int` values which means internally the property value is cast to `int` which will truncate the floating point - so in essence `1.1` will be truncated to `1` so will always be in range.

Simple fix, make sure your attribute knows you want to compare `double`'s and not `int` i.e.

```
[Range(0.0, 1.0)]
public decimal LowerDecimal { get; set; }
```